# Howto: use existing post_meta as options for a different metabox (checkboxes or list)

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, post-meta

1. I want to create an "Employee" Custom Post Type *("Add New Employee")* wherein the employee may belong to **one or many offices**.
2. The user needs to be able to add/edit/delete offices via a separate ***"Manage Offices*" page**
3. So that on the "Add New Employee" page, the user will see **all available offices as checkboxes**.
4. When the Employee Page is displayed in browser, all the selected offices show.

**The Problem:**

I know how to create the Employees CPT and also how to add/update meta boxes on that page, but I do not understand how to achieve items 2 and 3. I'm assuming I can still use meta boxes for the offices page, but does that mean I need a **new** CPT for the ***"Manage Offices"*** page?

**Another example ...**

In the Event Calendar Pro plugin there is a page to "Add Venues" wherein I can add:

1. Venue Title
2. Description
3. Featured Image
4. Address
5. etc.

Then on the "Add Event" page, there is a section called "Use Saved Venue" which is a dropdown list with the title of the Venues created from the "Add Venues" page.

**My question** (for clarification) is how to I pull in those values from "Add Venues" to use as input for the Add Event page? That is exactly what I'm trying to do in the above scenario.

Hope this is clear.

Please advise.

thanks

Comment: If you set offices as hierarchical taxonomy, all the work is just done: in admin pages you'll find the offices to check and in frontend you can show all the offices using [`the_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_terms)

Answer (score 0):

I was told about the fabulous [posts 2 posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/) plugin which does exactly what I need. Issue resolved.